# Difference between kafka batch and kafka request

Tags: apache-kafka, messagebroker

I was not able to find an satisfactory answer anywhere, sorry for if this question might look trivial:

In Kafka, on producer side, can a request contain multiple batches to different partitions ?
I see the words batch and requests are used as synonyms in the documentation, and I was hoping to find some clarity on this.

If yes, how does this affect the ack policy ?
Are acks on per batch or request basis ?

Answer (score 1):

A Kafka request (and response) is a message sent over the network between a Kafka client and broker. The Kafka protocol uses many types of requests, you can find them all in the [Kafka protocol documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#protocol_api_keys).

The Produce and Fetch requests are used to exchange records. They both contain Kafka batches, it's the `RECORDS` field in the protocol description. A Kafka batch is used to group several records together and saves some bytes by sharing the metadata for all records. You can find the exact format of a batch in the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#recordbatch).

TLDR:
Requests/responses are the full messages exchanged between Kafka clients and brokers. Some requests contain Kafka batches that are groups of records.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are asking about producer or consumer side. Here are some info that might answer your question.

**On producer side:**

By default, Kafka producer will accumulate records in a batch [up to 16KB](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_batch.size).
By default, the producer will have [up to 5 requests in flight](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#producerconfigs_max.in.flight.requests.per.connection), meaning that 5 batches can be sent to Kafka at the same time. Meanwhile, the producer start to accumulate data for the next batches.

The `acks` config controls the number of brokers required to answer in order to consider each request successful.

**On consumer side:**

By default, the Kafka consumer regularly calls `poll()` to get [a maximum of 500 records per poll](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_max.poll.records).

Also by default, the Kafka consumer [will ack every 5 seconds](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_auto.commit.interval.ms).

Meaning that the consumer will commit all the records that have been polled during the last 5 seconds by all the subsequent calls to `poll()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, my doubts are on producers side, the batches I am referring to are the batches for different partitions.